# "Factoring" SQLite DB connection in C

Tags: c, sqlite

Wasn't sure how to formulate this question... I'm working on a program using SQLite as DB. My problem is that I'm opening and closing my DB over and over at each query and I wanted to know if there's a propre way to avoid it in **C language**.

Here's the code that I always do before a request... My code is handled with functions.

```
   char *err_msg = 0;
   sqlite3_stmt *res;

   int rc = sqlite3_open(db_name, &db);

   if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {

       fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
       sqlite3_close(db);

       return 1;
   }

   char *sql = "SELECT * FROM table";

   rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &res, 0);
```

So my question is what can I do avoid opening my database and put it on my `rc` every time I wanna make a new query?

Is it possible to open it a single time at the beggining, pass my pointer variable to each function and auto-commit each sql query then close it at the exit points of my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a separate function to open the database connection and store it in a global variable.  Then anytime you need to access the database, just use that global.

Before you exit, call another function that closes the database connection.

Comment: I also had to extend my global variable so I could use it on side .c files. Thanks for the help @dbush !